# Running out of memory with an Amazon GPU instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, gpu

I have rented a GPU on Amazon AWS. it has the following description:

```
 ---------------------------------
| GPU Instance     |   g2.2xlarge |
| vCPUs            |   8          |
| Memory Gib       |   15         |
| Instance storage |   1x60 (SSD) |
 ---------------------------------
```

I transferred a 5 GB file and when trying to unzip it, it ran out of memory. the folder size after decompressing 5.23 GB.

When I run `df -h`, I got the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       20G   19G  4.0K 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7.4G  8.0K  7.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G  772K  1.5G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb        64G   52M   61G   1% /mnt
```

It seems that my data are stored in xvda1. can I store them in xvdb? if yes, will there be a difference in performance?

Answer (score 1):

xvdb is local "ephemeral storage" which is isn't persisted if you shut down the machine, I'd use it for temporary files and possibly copy input data there from S3 or other source.

Actually it should be faster than EBS-connected /dev/xvda1. Correct me if I'm wrong...

But be sure not to store the single copy of anything important there, for example source code which you are developing.

edit: Sorry for the mix-up, at beginning I wrote xvda1 when I meant xvdb. :/